# Why am I encountering a value error - (empty range for randrange)

Tags: python

I'm currently making a small python game and have run into this error: "ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)"
The code is simply running through a quiz using a quiz array (quiz1)

I can't seem to work out why this is happening, my hunch is that the range eventually gets to range(1,0) somehow even though it should stop.

```
test = len(quiz1)
while test>=1:
  questionNumber = random.randint(1,(len(quiz1)-1))
  question = quiz1.pop(questionNumber) 
  print(question[0])
  qnum = 1
  for i in question[1]:
    print(qnum, ".", i)
    qnum += 1
```

The array used is as follows

```
quiz1 = ['Dinosaur Quiz', ['What is the largest dinosaur thought to have existed?',['Argentinosaurus', 'Spinosaurus', 'Brachiosaurus'], 0],
                      ['Did Tyrannosaurus rex have feathers along its body?', ['Yes','No'], 1],
                      ['How tall was Velociraptor?',['3ft', '5ft', '7ft'], 0],
                      ['How many major geological time periods were there in the Mesozoic era?', ['1', '5', '3'], 2],
                      ['Who discovered and named the first Utahraptor specimen?',['James Kirkland','Jack Horner', 'Carl Limoni'], 0],
                        ]
```

The while loop (while test>= 1) should stop the loop running when the the randrange is an empty range but it continues. Does anyone know why I'm encountering the error? (ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0))

Comment: i think `question = ` line should be indented. anyway, `test` is never changed inside the loop, so you can't expect the loop to stop

Comment: oops. even if i change test back to len(quiz1), i still get the error even though it is changed inside the loop (the length decreases every time a question is picked)

Comment: try doing `print(test)` immediately after your `while` line and see if its value changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code to put in correct formatting and some missing punctuation (see below). The problem is you have:

```
test = len(quiz1)
while test>=1: #missing colon added
```

But test is never modified in the loop, which must now loop indefinitely. Every time you pop a value from `quiz1`, its length is reduced by 1 and eventually will have a length of 1. When that happens, the second parameter in the call to `randint` will be 0 while the first parameter is 1 and that is an impossible range.

Corrected code:

```
import random

quiz1 = ['Dinosaur Quiz', ['What is the largest dinosaur thought to have existed?',['Argentinosaurus', 'Spinosaurus', 'Brachiosaurus'], 0],
                      ['Did Tyrannosaurus rex have feathers along its body?', ['Yes','No'], 1],
                      ['How tall was Velociraptor?',['3ft', '5ft', '7ft'], 0],
                      ['How many major geological time periods were there in the Mesozoic era?', ['1', '5', '3'], 2],
                      ['Who discovered and named the first Utahraptor specimen?',['James Kirkland','Jack Horner', 'Carl Limoni'], 0],
                        ]

while len(quiz1)>1:
    questionNumber = random.randint(1,(len(quiz1)-1))
    question = quiz1.pop(questionNumber)
    print(question[0])
    qnum = 1
    for i in question[1]:
        print(qnum, ".", i)
        qnum += 1
```

Your loop:

```
    qnum = 1
    for i in question[1]:
        print(qnum, ".", i)
        qnum += 1
```

Can be simplified and neatened up with:

```
    for n, q in enumerate(question[1]):
        print(n + 1, ". ", q, sep='')
```

Or if you are running with Python 3.6 or greater:

```
    for n, q in enumerate(question[1]):
        print(f'{n + 1}. {q}')
```

Or for any version of Python:

```
    for n, q in enumerate(question[1]):
        print('{}. {}'.format(n + 1, q))
```

Comment: Ah, thank so much! (the missing colon was an error in copying it over :p )

Answer (score 0):

The issue you having is related to array indexing. Array indexes in python start from 0, but you use `random.randint(1, (len(quiz1)-1))` instead. So before the array is empieted by the pop, when you end up having a single question, you get `random.randint(1, 1)` which is 1, but the element in the array is indexed at 0.
Using `random.randint(0, (len(quiz1)-1))` (alongside `test -= 1` in the loop) fixes it.

Working code:

```
import random

quiz1 = [
    'Dinosaur Quiz',
        ['What is the largest dinosaur thought to have existed?', [
            'Argentinosaurus', 'Spinosaurus', 'Brachiosaurus'], 0],
        ['Did Tyrannosaurus rex have feathers along its body?', ['Yes', 'No'], 1],
        ['How tall was Velociraptor?', ['3ft', '5ft', '7ft'], 0],
        ['How many major geological time periods were there in the Mesozoic era?', [
            '1', '5', '3'], 2],
        ['Who discovered and named the first Utahraptor specimen?',
            ['James Kirkland', 'Jack Horner', 'Carl Limoni'], 0],
]
test = len(quiz1)

while test >= 1:
    questionNumber = random.randint(0, (len(quiz1)-1))
    question = quiz1.pop(questionNumber)
    print(question[0])
    qnum = 1
    test -= 1
```

Output:

```
D
Did Tyrannosaurus rex have feathers along its body?
Who discovered and named the first Utahraptor specimen?
How many major geological time periods were there in the Mesozoic era?
How tall was Velociraptor?
```